# Prove that with given conditions regular functions give regular curve.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry, curves

If $x_i(t)$ $i=1,..,n$ ($n=2,3$) regular functions($k$ times continuously differentiable  functions) and $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i^\prime(t))>0$ $n=2,3,t\in(a,b)$ then

$x_i=(x_i(t))$ is equation for regular cuve.

Now proof starts with saying that we need only to prove that it is local bijective map.But we need also that inverse of map to be continuous as well.I don't know why author does not prove this or maybe this follows from given conditions which I can't understand.

Comment: What is your definition of a regular curve? Isn’t it a curve with non zero derivative everywhere?

Comment: @IvinBabu my book defines regular curve as a curve if every $\gamma(t) $ point has neighbourhood on which part of a curve can be regular parametrized $\gamma(t)=x_i(t)$

Comment: $x_i(t)$ are  k  times continuously differentiable functions

Comment: But then isn’t the given $x_i(t)$ the required regular parametrization?

Comment: @IvinBabu They are just regular functions. We want to know given that regular functions $x_i(t)$ in what conditions they describe regular curve.